# Sharing particular data between realms

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am about to start working on the back-end for a mobile app (initially iOS/Android, later also website) and I am thinking whether Realm could fulfill all my needs.

The basic idea is that there are two types of users - customers and service-providers. The customers send requests to the server once in a while and are subscribed (real-time) for any event that might occur in relation to this request in the future. Each service-provider is listening for specific requests from all customers and is the one who is going to trigger various events (send data) for each of those requests.

From the Realm docs, it is obvious that the real-time data sync is not going to be a problem. The thing I am concerned about is how to model the scenario (customer/service-provider) in the Realm 'world'. Based on what I read, it is preferred to have one realm per user. Therefore, I suppose the user will register and will be given a realm. Then whenever he makes a request, it is going to be stored in his realm. Now the question is how to model the service-provider. There are going to be various service-providers each responding (triggering various kinds of events up to one hour after request) to different kinds of requests. (Each user can send any request and therefore be served by any service-provider.)

I read a bit about that Realm supports data sharing among different realms which could be a partial solution for this problem, however I was not able to find if this 'sharing' could share only particular requests. (Meaning each service-provider will get only requests intended for him.)

My question is whether this scenario is doable using Realm?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a perfect fit for Realm's server-side [event-handling](https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/pe-ee/#event-handling). Put simply, Realm offers the ability through our Node SDK to listen for changes across Realms on the server.

So in your example, where each mobile user would have their own Realm, the URL for this would be `/~/myRealm` in which the tilde represents the Realm user ID. The Node SDK event handling API allows you to register a JS function that will run in response to changes represented by a Regex pattern for Realm URLs. In this case you could use: `^/([0-9a-f]+)/myRealm` so that any time any user's `myRealm` updated, the server could perform some logic.

In this manner, the server via the Node SDK is really a "super-user" or service-provider as you describe. When an event fires, the JS function that runs is provided the Realm that was updated and a list of indexes pertaining to the objects in the Realm that were inserted, deleted, or modified. You can then perform any logic in JS, such as using the changed data to call out to another API or opening the Realm in question or any other and writing changes which will get pushed back out to the respective clients.

The full server-side event handling is part of Realm Professional Edition, but we recently released another way to interact with this called [Realm Functions](https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/#realm-functions). This provides the ability through the server's dashboard to create the same JS functions that will run in response to changes across Realms. The developer edition support 3 functions so you can try it out immediately!

Comment: If I understand it correctly, I will hook up for any changes across all realms, find out which service-provider should receive this event and then insert it into it's realm, so the realm 'engine' will notify all connected clients to this realm (in realm time). My only concern is the data duplication as the record will be stored in two realms at the same time but I suppose we cannot get around this... (There is nothing like creating only pointers to rows as means of sharing data between realms, the data is actually duplicated, right?)

Comment: Right now data will need to be duplicated across Realm's but in the future we do plan to offer support for syncing subsets of data from a single Realm to clients, so that you could just add a link or adjust a property to make it fit the subset sent to a particular group of clients.